# Azure recover deleted database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've accidentally deleted my Azure web site which was linked to database, and now my Database is gone.

Is there any way I can recover data from database ?

Comment: Contact support immediately. They might be able to recover the database.

Comment: FYI - SQL Database, Premium Edition, will have 'self-service restore' to undo actions such as these. Doesn't help you in this situation, but it's a consideration for you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using web and business edition databases, you should rely on DB Copy and export to generate *.bacpac files.

The self-service restore is now supported on all new service tiers: Basic, Standard, and Premium, with different retention policy. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx

Answer (score 19):

In the [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com/):

- On the left menu, click 'All Resources'
- Select the Sql Server from which the database was deleted
- Scroll down to the 'Operations' section
- Click 'Deleted databases'
- Select the database to restore
- Review the information and click OK

[image: Deleted databases]

Note that restoring a backup from the list can still fail if it's outside the retention period for your pricing tier.